# Access DataFrame object in DataFrame method call

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

Instead of using the name of the dataframe object I am calling the method on, is there a shorthand name for it?
Eg., Suppose I want to do something like

```
   long_data_frame_name.long_column_name.fillna(long_data_frame_name.long_column_name.mean())
```

I'd like to be able to shorten this into something like

```
  long_data_frame_name.long_column_name.fillna(self.mean())
```

Self doesn't work (I tried it :)). I think in `R plyr` there's `.` which does what I'm asking.

Edit: Just to be clear I know I can assign my long winded variable to another variable but I was hoping to avoid cluttering up the name space with temporary variables.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can create a shorthand reference beforehand. For example:

```
ldfn = long_data_frame_name.long_column_name
```

and then do:

```
ldfn.fillna(ldfn.mean(), inplace=True)
```

The `inplace=True` is required, because otherwise `.fillna` will return a new `DataFrame` object rather than updating the one you provide.

Here is a complete example. First we set up the demo `DataFrame` with a missing value:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((5,5)), columns=['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee'])
df.iloc[2,2] = np.nan
df

   aa   bb   cc   dd   ee
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Next we fill, using `inplace=True`, and see the fill applied on the original `DataFrame` object `df`:

```
dflc = df.cc
dflc.fillna(dflc.mean(), inplace=True)
df

    aa   bb   cc   dd   ee
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I think it misses the point of my question. I know I can assign my long winded variable to another variable but I was hoping to avoid cluttering up the name space with temporary variables.

Comment: Then the answer is just "No." :)